# Grouping a linq query with an external list with no gaps

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-entities

I need to get the data for a line graph from a database where the stream goes back from the current date n days/weeks/months/years grouped by those timespans.

The records in the DB have a DateTime associated with them.

Given a list of date ranges (start of a day to the end of a day or start of a week to the end of a week) how can I get a continuous stream using linq?

It's important that there are no gaps in the stream in the case that there happen to be no records for that date range. It should just return a zero.

Here's what I tried but it doesnt return any values.

```
    Dim ranges = Enumerable.Range(0, itemCount).Select(Function(x) DateTime.Now.AddDays(-x).Date).ToList()

    Dim stream = Await DB.LogEntries.
        OfType(Of LogEntryContentView).
        GroupBy(Function(x) DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DateStamp)).
        Where(Function(x) ranges.Any(Function(y) y < x.Key AndAlso DbFunctions.AddDays(y, 1) > x.Key)).
        OrderBy(Function(x) x.Key).
        Select(Function(x) x.Count()).
        ToListAsync()
```

(Answers in either C# or VB.NET are fine, I know both)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is by using `.ToLookup(...)`.

You query would look (something) like this:

```
Dim ranges = Enumerable.Range(0, itemCount).Select(Function(x) DateTime.Now.AddDays(-x).Date).ToList()

Dim stream = DB.LogEntries.
    OfType(Of LogEntryContentView).
    GroupBy(Function(x) DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DateStamp)).
    Where(Function(x) ranges.Any(Function(y) y < x.Key AndAlso DbFunctions.AddDays(y, 1) > x.Key)).
    ToLookup(Function(x) x.Key)

Dim results = ranges.Select(Function (d) stream(d).Count()).ToList()
```

You'd need to get the async stuff working, but the lookup nicely does the trick of making sure you include all days, including those without data.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a hybrid approach where you create a static table of Periods(which stores all the possible ranges) and then joining on them:

```
db.LogEntries.Join(db.Periods, a=> true, b => true, (a,b) = > new {LE=a, P=b})
.Where (p=> p.LE.DateStamp >= p.P.PeriodStartDate && p.LE.DateStamp <= p.P.PeriodEndDate)
.OrderBy(p=> p.P.PeriodStartDate)
.GroupBy(p=> new{Start=p.P.PeriodStartDate, End=p.P.PeriodEndDate})
.Select(p=> new{Start=p.Key.Start, End=p.P.End, Count=p.Count()})
```